# how to convert video to gif image with audio in android using ffmpeg?

Tags: android

I want convert video which upload from gallery or camera into GIF image with audio using FFMPEG andorid.Please give me proper solution for create gif image with sound.Please help me
Thanks in adavace

Comment: Please note that SO is not "give me solution with free code" kind of site. What do you try so far? (btw - gif with sound doesnt exists...)

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to accomplish is **impossible**.

The `.gif` format does not support Audio. If you need audio and video in the same file, you should use a container format such as `.ogg`, `.webm`, `.mkv`, or `.mp4`.